# push_back into 2D vector is seg faulting

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to sort a vector of points by both x and y, so that my resulting vector will read left to right, top to bottom. My original idea of just sorting by one and then the other ends up with a disordered vector, so I decided to sort by one, then put each set of points with the same x coordinate into a separate vector within a vector of vectors. After it is divided, I will sort each vector individually.

My else if statement is complex because of the way I gather points, which produces unavoidable error.

```
void sortPoints(vector<Point> coor, vector< vector<Point> >& output) {
    sort(coor.begin(), coor.end(), sortY);
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < coor.size(); i++) {
        Point co = coor[i];
        if(i == 0) { output[j].push_back(co); }
        else if((co.x == coor[i-1].x) || ((co.x - 1) == coor[i-1].x) || 
            (co.x == (coor[i-1].x - 1)) || ((co.x - 2) == coor[i-1].x) || 
                (co.x == (coor[i-1].x - 2))) {
            output[j].push_back(co);
        }
        else j++;
    }
}
```

I know that the seg fault happens during output[j].push_back(co).

I have looked up syntax, and made sure my declaration is right, and it all seems fine. I was thinking maybe it's because of the vector of points? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How is `output` declared? Does it have enough space so that `output[j]` is valid?

Comment: *I have looked up syntax* -- `output[j].push_back(` -- change that to `output.at(j).push_back(`.  I bet you will see the issue then and not get a seg fault (an exception will be thrown instead of a seg fault).

Comment: We can make some pretty good guesses on what's wrong, but without a [mcve] the best we can do is guess. If you make a MCVE to turn this into a good question, my money is  on you seeing and solving the bug yourself as a result of making the MCVE.  Odds are also good that you'll see ways to improve your code as well.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It is declared the same as in the function declaration, and it allows me to use 'output[i][j]', and 'output[i].begin()', so I think that is valid.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right, when I changed it to at it throws an exception: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
I've gotten what() before, but I don't remember what it is.

Comment: And @user4581301 I already did that, that's how I know exactly where the fault is coming from. I didn't think posting nothing but 'output[j].push_back(co)' would be very useful for you guys.

Comment: @tydcghk -- That's the exception telling you that the vector has 0 size, but you're trying to access element 0.  See how that works?

Comment: @tydcghk Minimal and COMPLETE. Often the bug isn't where the program finally chokes and dies; it's where the program was set up to choke and die. Without an example that includes how `output` was initialized and used before the error occurs, we can only guess what state `output` is in. But if the example contains something along the lines of `vector< vector<Point> > output;` and makes no attempts to insert anything into `output` before `output[j].push_back(co)`, the time between you posting the question and someone posting a verifiable, correct  answer would be seconds.

Comment: A proper MCVE for this problem could be as simple as `#include <vector> int main() { std::vector<int> vec; vec[0] = 42; }`, and if you haven't figured out what the problem is by that point, you didn't read any credible `vector` documentation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I do see that, but I thought you only needed to allocate memory for vectors when using pointers. Or am I using pointers without realizing it? I've used malloc() before, but I think that's specific to pointers.

Comment: @tydcghk -- Vectors must be sized appropriately before you access items in it.  If the vector is empty, then you can't access element 0.

Answer (score 1):

The segfault happens, because you are not pushing into the vector of vectors, but in

```
output[j].push_back(co);
```

you are trying to push into the `vector<Point>`: `output[j]`. However (here i have to guess because you dont show how you initialize `output`), it seems like you didnt create a vector at position of `j` before trying to use it.

You need something like:

```
std::vector<Point> temp;
temp.push_back(co);
output.push_back(temp);
```

Comment: Shouldn't 'output[j]' make it so the push_back command pushes a point into the vector j?

Comment: @tydcghk `output[j]` is accessing an index where there is no vector yet. `output` is a `vector<vector<Point>>`. Before you can push a `Point` into a vector you need to create a `vector<Point>` either as in the answer or by calling `output.resize(number_of_vectors)` or by initializing `output` properly